# GWT DataGrid automatic height

Tags: gwt, datagrid

I'm trying to insert a gwt datagrid in my application. If i set a static height (500px) everything works nice. But i want to make the dataGrid auto adjust to screen size. With height 100% i get a blank screen.
i've also tried to put the datagrid into a resizeLayoutPanel with the same results.

any tips?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

All `RequiresResize` widgets should be given an explicit size, or be added to `ProvidesResize` widgets (up to a `RootLayoutPanel` or a `ProvidesResize` widget with an explicit size; the only exception is `ResizeLayoutPanel` which doesn't implement `ProvidesResize` because it couldn't honor the contract for its header and footer widgets, but it definitely honors it for the center widget).

So the question is: where did you add your `DataGrid` and/or `ResizeLayoutPanel`?

Comment: The key point was ...be added to ProvidesResize widgets (up to a RootLayoutPanel). The parent panel was HTMLPanel and it is not a ProvidesResize widget.

Comment: You should "accept" the answer instead of changing the question title to "solved". See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 3):

Thomas Broyer is correct. Nonetheless I found something of interest concerning the DataGrid (it does not happen in CellTable). 
If you are using a DeckPanel and if you are creating the DataGrid on a hidden Panel of this DeckPanel, than the data of the DataGrid will not be visible if you show the panel of the DataGrid. 
I found only one workaround: call addDataDisplay of your DataProvider "after" the panel was made visible.

Comment: In most browsers, height and width of hidden div's (i.e. styled display:none) is not available to lay out the rest of the page. There are tricks to work around it, so I guess CellTable implemented it, while DataGrid didn't (or couldn't because it is slightly more complex)

Comment: Confirmed that this also affects a TabLayoutPanel where the DataGrid is not on the default tab.