# GWT DataGrid not shown

Tags: java, gwt, datagrid, uibinder

I'm trying to update my data widget from a `CellTable` to `DataGrid` and I basically thought I online a change from  `@UiField CellTable<T>` to `@UiField DataGrid<T>` but thats not it.

```
private void init() {
        sortHandler = new ListHandler<GWTUser>(getUsers());

        dataGrid.setWidth("100%");
        dataGrid.setHeight("100%");
        dataGrid.setAutoHeaderRefreshDisabled(true);
        dataGrid.setEmptyTableWidget(emptyDb);
        dataGrid.addColumnSortHandler(sortHandler);
        dataGrid.setVisibleRangeAndClearData(dataGrid.getVisibleRange(), true);

        dataGrid.setRowCount(1, true);
        dataGrid.clearTableWidth();
        dataGrid.redraw();

        // Setup Cell Table.
        initCellTable();

        // Connect the table to the data provider.
        dataProvider.addDataDisplay(dataGrid);

    }

    private void initCellTable() {

        // userId Column
        TextColumn<GWTUser> userIdColumn = new TextColumn<GWTUser>() {

            @Override
            public String getValue(GWTUser object) {
                return object.getUserId();
            }

        };
        dataGrid.addColumn(userIdColumn, Lang.LABEL_USER_USERID);

        dataGrid.addColumnSortHandler(sortHandler);
        dataGrid.getColumnSortList().push(userIdColumn);
        dataGrid.getColumnSortList().push(userIdColumn);

    }

    @Override
    public void setUserList(List<GWTUser> users) {

            setUsers(users);

            dataGrid.setRowCount(getUsers().size(), true);
            dataGrid.setRowData(0, getUsers());
            dataGrid.setPageSize(getUsers().size());
            dataGrid.setVisibleRange(new Range(0,dataGrid.getRowCount()));
            dataGrid.redraw();

            sortHandler.setList(getUsers());


    }
```

uiBinder:

```
    <g:VerticalPanel>                               
        <g:ScrollPanel ui:field="listScrollPanel">
            <c:DataGrid styleName= ui:field='dataGrid' width="100%" height="98%"/>
        </g:ScrollPanel>

        <g:HorizontalPanel>
            <g:Button ui:field="createButton">New</g:Button>
            <g:Button ui:field="refreshButton">Refresh</g:Button>
            <g:Button ui:field="removeSelectedButton">Delete Selection</g:Button>
        </g:HorizontalPanel>

    </g:VerticalPanel>
```

When I change the region where my `DataGrid` should be with the chrome dev tool, the data with the tables is there but not shown.

as basic information: `init` is called by the constructor and `setUserList` is called in my activitiy when I get the data from a rest service. thanks for any help.

Comment: You'll have to set the height to an explicit value like `500px`. [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874168/gwt-datagrid-automatic-height).

Comment: works fine thx, but now i have to redesign everything to make it dynamic again ....

Comment: Great, I've added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataGrid` requires an explicitly set height. This means that you can't use percentages (e.g. `100%`), but rather have to use something like `500px`.

Here is a related question:

[GWT DataGrid automatic height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874168/gwt-datagrid-automatic-height)

Comment: I'm having a `ResizeLayoutPanel`around everything and I'm trying to resize it by `void onListContentResize(ResizeEvent event) { dataGrid.setHeight(Integer.toString(event.getHeight()));
listScrollPanel.setPixelSize(event.getWidth(), event.getHeight()-80); } is this now even possible with a `CellTable` it worked.

Comment: @vicR Try `dataGrid.setHeight(Integer.toString(event.getHeight()) + "px");`

Comment: is it possible that i need to call `redraw()` after my height change ? but doesn't it cost a lot of computing time?

Comment: oh. sorry my mistake.